# Implement Filtering with Custom Adapter in Android with C#

Tags: c#, android, filter, custom-adapter

I'm trying to implement Filter in ActionBar with Custom Adapter.

My custom Adapter implements IFilterable. And my Filter getter in custom adapter looks like:

```
public Filter Filter { 
        get
        {
            if (tdFilter == null){
                tdFilter = new TodoItemFilter();
                tdFilter.OriginalData = this._originaltodoItemList;
                tdFilter.TdAdapter = this;
            }
            return tdFilter;
        }
    }
```

I have created an ItemFilter class.

My overriden PerformFiltering method in ItemFilter.cs code looks like:

```
protected override Filter.FilterResults PerformFiltering(Java.Lang.ICharSequence constraint)
    {

        FilterResults oreturn = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint == null || constraint.Length() == 0)
        {
            oreturn.Values = this.OriginalData.ToJavaObject();
            oreturn.Count = this.OriginalData.Length;
        }
        else
        {
            string[] actualResults = new string[this.originalData.Length];
            List<TodoItem> tdiList = new List<TodoItem> ();
            int i=0;
            foreach (TodoItem td in this.originalData)
            {
                if(td.Name.ToUpperInvariant().StartsWith(constraint.ToString().ToUpperInvariant())){
                    tdiList.Add (td);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            oreturn.Values = tdiList.ToJavaObject();
            oreturn.Count = tdiList.Count;
        }

        return oreturn;
    }
```

My overriden Publishresults method looks like:

```
protected override void PublishResults(Java.Lang.ICharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results)
    {
        if (results.Count == 0)
            this.TdAdapter.NotifyDataSetInvalidated();
        else
        {
            var propertyInfo = ((JavaHolder)results.Values).Instance;
            TdAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

And my JavaHolder class looks like:

```
public class JavaHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
  public readonly object Instance;

  public JavaHolder(object instance)
  {
     Instance = instance;
  }
}
```

My "PerformFiltering" method is working fine.

But, in my "PublishResults" method, I'm unable to convert the results.Values to my .NET object (TodoItem[]). TdAdapter is my Custom adapter.

```
TdAdapter._originaltodoItemList = ((JavaHolder)results.Values).Instance;
```

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Am I missing something?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work.

My "PublishResults" method now looks like this:

```
protected override void PublishResults(Java.Lang.ICharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results)
    {
        if (results.Count == 0)
            this.TdAdapter.NotifyDataSetInvalidated();
        else
        {
            System.Object obj = results.Values.ToNetObject<System.Object>();

            IEnumerable enumerable = obj as IEnumerable;

            List<TodoItem> LTdi = new List<TodoItem> ();

            if (enumerable != null)
            {
                foreach(object element in enumerable)
                {
                    LTdi.Add (element as TodoItem);
                }
            }

            TdAdapter._originaltodoItemList = LTdi.ToArray();
            TdAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

And it is working perfectly as expected.